# I get error when I'm trying to rename folder in Xcode project

Tags: xcode, rename, group

I create a new group(folder), try to rename it, and an error occurs(it says: "Failed to rename file as the source file 'swift/TaskCreator/TaskCreator/New Group1' does n…")

Detail info:

```
Details

Failed to rename file as the source file 'swift/TaskCreator/TaskCreator/New Group1' does not exist.
Domain: com.apple.dt.SourceControlErrorDomain
Code: -1104
User Info: {
    DVTErrorCreationDateKey = "2023-06-18 21:01:29 +0000";
}
--


System Information

macOS Version 13.4 (Build 22F66)
Xcode 14.3.1 (21815) (Build 14E300c)
Timestamp: 2023-06-19T00:01:29+03:00
```

If I restart Xcode, I can change name for a folder only once, then the error comes back again. Has anyone faced this issue?

I reinstalled Xcode, but it didn't help me.

Comment: Open your project folder and look at it directly.

Comment: I see that there is a folder with the name I assigned to it(using Finder), but in Xcode this folder is still called "new group".

Comment: "with the name I assigned to it(using Finder)" So you changed the folder's name *directly in the Finder*?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This project is hosed. Make a new project and migrate your code files into it. Use drag and drop or copy and paste and work entirely within Xcode and the project navigator.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Could you explain to me why this happened? And how can I prevent the error next time

Comment: Never look inside the project folder in the Finder.